# Cannot find symbol: symbol: class SimpleDate location: class SimpleDateClient

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans. These files are not able to run for some reason. I am trying to import the other files that I have in tabs in Netbeans, but they are not working. How can I make this application run `SimpleDateClient.java` as the main method as well.

This is `SimpleDateClient.java`

```
/* A client program to display SimpleDate object values
   Anderson, Franceschi
*/
package SimpleDateClient;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class SimpleDateClient extends JFrame
{
  private String action = "";

  private int animationPause = 2; // 2 seconds between animations


  private SimpleDate dateObj; // declare SimpleDate object reference

  public void workWithDates( )
  {
    animate( "dateObj reference declared" );

    /***** Add your code here *****/
    /**** 1. Instantiate dateObj using an empty argument list  */
    dateObj = new SimpleDate();


    animate( "Instantiated dateObj - empty argument list" );

    /***** 2. Set the month to the month you were born */


    //animate( "Set month to birth month" );


    /***** 3. Set the day to the day of the month you were born */


    //animate( "Set day to birth day" );


    /***** 4. Set the year to the year you were born */


    //animate( "Set year to birth year" );


    /***** 5. Call the nextDay method */


    //animate( "Set the date to the next day" );


    /***** 6. Set the day to 32, an illegal value */


    //animate( "Set day to 32" );


    /***** 7. Set the month to 13, an illegal value */


    //animate( "Set month to 13" );


    /***** 8. Assign the value null to dateObj */


    //animate( "Set object reference to null" );


    /***** 9. Attempt to set the month to 1 */

  }

  public SimpleDateClient( )
  {
    super( "A SimpleDate Object" );

    setSize( 300, 300 );
    setVisible( true );
  }

  public void paint( Graphics g )
  {
    super.paint( g );

    // display action
    g.drawString( action, 50, 250 );

    // object reference
    int sX = 50, sY = 75;
    int boxL = 75, boxH = 20;
    g.drawRect( sX, sY, boxL, boxH );
    g.drawString( "dateObj", sX, sY - 10 );

    if ( dateObj != null )
       draw( g );
    else
      g.drawString( "null", sX + 15, sY + 15 );
  }

  public void draw( Graphics g )
  {
    int sX = 50, sY = 75;
    int boxL = 75, boxH = 20;

    // arrow
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL, sY + boxH / 2,
                sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH / 2 );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH / 2,
                sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH * 2 );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL + 25 - 5, sY + boxH * 2 - 5,
                sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH * 2 );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL + 25 + 5, sY + boxH * 2 - 5,
                sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH * 2 );


    // month
    g.drawString( "month", sX + boxL - 50, sY + 2 * boxH + 15 );
    g.drawRect( sX + boxL, sY + 2 * boxH, boxL, boxH );
    g.drawString( Integer.toString( dateObj.getMonth( ) ),
                   sX + boxL + 5, sY + 2 * boxH + 15 );

    // day
    g.drawString( "day", sX + boxL - 50, sY + 3 * boxH + 15 );
    g.drawRect( sX + boxL, sY + 3 * boxH, boxL, boxH );
    g.drawString( Integer.toString( dateObj.getDay( ) ),
                  sX + boxL + 5, sY + 3 * boxH + 15 );

    // year
    g.drawString( "year", sX + boxL - 50, sY + 4 * boxH + 15 );
    g.drawRect( sX + boxL, sY + 4 * boxH, boxL, boxH );
    g.drawString( Integer.toString( dateObj.getYear( ) ),
                  sX + boxL + 5, sY + 4 * boxH + 15 );
  }

  public void animate( String a )
  {
    action = a;
    repaint( );
    Pause.wait( (double) animationPause );
  }

  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    SimpleDateClient app = new SimpleDateClient( );
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    app.workWithDates( );
  }
}
```

This is `SimpleDate.java`

```
/* A simple date class
   Anderson, Franceschi
*/
package SimpleDateClient;


public class SimpleDate
{
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  /** default constructor
  *  sets month to 1, day to 1 and year to 2000
  */
  public SimpleDate( )
  {
    setDate( 1, 1, 2000 );
  }

  /** overloaded constructor
  *  @param mm    initial value for month
  *  @param dd    initial value for day
  *  @param yyyy  initial value for year
  *
  *  passes parameters to set methods
  */
  public SimpleDate( int mm, int dd, int yyyy )
  {
    setMonth( mm );
    setYear( yyyy );
    setDay( dd );
  }

  /* accessor methods */
  int getMonth( ) { return month; }
  int getDay( )   { return day; }
  int getYear( )  { return year; }

  /** mutator method */
  /** setMonth
  *  @param mm new value for month
  *  if mm is between 1 and 12, sets month to mm
  *  otherwise, sets month to 1
  */
  public void setMonth( int mm )
  {
    month = ( mm >= 1 && mm <= 12 ? mm : 1 );
  }

  /** setDay
  *  @param dd new value for day
  *  if dd is legal day for current month, sets day to dd
  *  otherwise, sets day to 1
  */
  public void setDay( int dd )
  {
    day = ( dd >= 1 && isValidDay( dd ) ? dd : 1 );
  }

  /** setYear
  *  @param yyyy new value for year
  *  sets year to yyyy
  */
  public void setYear( int yyyy )
  {
    year = yyyy;
  }

  /** sets date to the next day
  */
  public void nextDay( )
  {
     if ( ! isValidDay( ++day ) )
     {
         day = 1;
         if ( ++month > 12 )
         {
             month = 1;
             year++;
         }
     }
  }

  private boolean isValidDay( int newDay )
  {
     int [] daysInMonth = { 0, 31, 28, 31,
                                30, 31, 30,
                                31, 31, 30,
                               31, 30, 31 };

    if ( newDay > daysInMonth[month] )
    {
       if ( month == 2 && isLeapYear( ) && newDay == 29 )
          return true;
       else
          return false;
    }
    else
       return true;

  }

  private boolean isLeapYear( )
  {
     return !( year % 4 != 0
               ||( year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0 ) );
  }


  /** setDate
  *  @param mm    new value for month
  *  @param dd    new value for day
  *  @param yyyy  new value for year
  *  passes parameters to setMonth, setDay, and setYear
  */
  public void setDate( int mm, int dd, int yyyy )
  {
    setYear( yyyy );  // set year first (could be leap year)
    setMonth( mm );   // set month next
    setDay( dd );     // set day
  }

  /** toString
  *  @return String
  *  returns date in mm/dd/yyyy format
  */
  public String toString( )
  {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

  /** equals
  *  @param   d  Object to compare to this object
  *  @return  true if d is equal to this object
  *           false, otherwise
  */
  public boolean equals( Object d )
  {
    if ( !( d instanceof SimpleDate ) )
       return false;
    SimpleDate d1 = (SimpleDate)d;
    if ( month == d1.month
         && day == d1.day
         && year == d1.year )
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

This is `Pause.java`

```
/* Pause class to pause applications
   Anderson, Franceschi
*/
package SimpleDateClient;

public class Pause
{
  public static void wait( double seconds )
  {
     try
     {
       Thread.sleep( (int) ( seconds * 1000 ) );
     }
     catch ( InterruptedException e )
     {
       e.printStackTrace( );
     }
  }
}
```

[image: For the SimpleDate class, it is giving me an error along with the Pause class]

[image: Pause]

[image: Files]

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me, however.  Don't use `Thread.sleep` within Swing, this WILL cause issues for you, Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe, this means that you should NEVER update the state of the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread nor should you block the EDT with any long running tasks (like `Thread.sleep`.  Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, there are too many issues which could screw up your paint code, instead, use a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` and put your custom painting there.  Then add the panel to what ever container your like. [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Oh, and you should be starting your code within the context of the EDT, which will solve a ton of possible issues, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: *"I am trying to import the other files that I have in tabs in Netbeans, but they are not working"* - Are they actually in the same project?  Based on your `package` declarations, you don't need to add any `import` statements for these classes, as they are in the same package space

Comment: @MadProgrammer they are not even in a project. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'd be really curious as to know how you created any files without having a project

Comment: I click File > Open File @MadProgrammer

Comment: Click `File > New Project`, copy ALL the files into the src directory, make sure you've setup the packages correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Goto `File | New Project`

[image: Project]

Select `Java` from the `Categories` and `Java Application` from the `Projects`, click `Next >`

[image: New Project]

Name the project and make sure you set up the initial package/class

[image: Project Properties]

You should now have the beginings of your project.

[image: Project Navigator]

It's now a choice as to whether you copy the existing files into the project (under Windows you can simply copy the files from the Explorer and paste them into the project (under the `src` node)) or create empty classes within the project and simply copy paste the contents from the original files

Comment: Oh hell, thanks a lot man. I actually just did it right before you posted this. You really are a mad programmer. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it.

Hover over the project. Right click. Click on `Properties`. 
[image]

Click `Add Folder...` next to the `Source Package Folders:` Then select the file or folder you want to use. Then click `Ok`.
[image]